# Flex&Bison: define main function in a separate file

Tags: function, bison, program-entry-point, flex-lexer

I am trying to make a small interpreter using Flex and Bison.

Now I have two files: `parser.l` and `parser.y`. Usually, main function is put in `parser.y` file. What I want to do is to put the main function in a different file `main.cpp` which makes my package look neat.

```c
#include "y.tab.h"

int main()
{
   yyparse();
   return 0;
}
```

But when I compile, I got an error:

```
undefined reference to `main'
```

So I know there is something wrong to include `y.tab.h`.

Could you someone to tell me how to do it?

### Solution

I just figured it out:
add the following to your main.c file:

```
    extern FILE *yyin;
    extern FILE *yyout;
    extern int yyparse(void);
```

Comment: I retagged this from Adobe Flex to Gnu-Flex.

Comment: You don't really need `yyin` or `yyout` since you don't (yet) reference them from the file containing `main()`.  However, if you end up doing work such as reading from files specified on the command line instead of standard input, you may need them.  It would be nice if Bison generated a header with the appropriate declarations in it.  The `y.tab.h` file is not, however, the place for that information; it is used to convey information between the parser and the lexical analyzer, not between the application and the parser.

Answer (score 1):

SO noted:

> I just figured it out: add the following to your main.c file:
>
> `extern FILE *yyin; 
>   extern FILE *yyout; 
>   extern int yyparse(void);`

@Jonathan Leffler Noted

> You don't really need `yyin` or `yyout` since you don't (yet) reference
>   them from the file containing `main()`. However, if you end up doing
>   work such as reading from files specified on the command line instead
>   of standard input, you may need them. It would be nice if Bison
>   generated a header with the appropriate declarations in it. The
>   `y.tab.h` file is not, however, the place for that information; it is
>   used to convey information between the parser and the lexical
>   analyzer, not between the application and the parser.